# Is there a way to have page insights ignore a script

Tags: javascript, animation, pagespeed

I have implemented Kevin Hugnagl's version of the strip gradient on my website and am running in to the issue that when testing speed on page speed insight the scoring accounts for the entirety of the script to complete before it considers the loading complete. This creates a false positive kind of scenario where the user has full interaction and usability of the page in the same amount of time with the script enabled or disabled. But since the script takes about 28 seconds to complete page speed insight assumes this script needs to complete before it considers the page loaded. It seems that in a scenario like this it would make sense that google page speed scoring and page speed insights should somehow be instructed or made aware that a particular script should not be accounted for in their metrics.

If the script is enabled it will fail gtmetrix as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: For your own insights, just ignore it. For the google speed scoring, I very much doubt there is a way to tell them that your page is faster than they measured, or everyone would use this for seo-boosting.

Comment: Hi Bergi, you pretty much nailed it that this is related to SEO. I have been playing around with loading the script using deferred and asynchronous methods and am getting some really interesting results in that page insights will swing from 1.6s up to 34s to interactive. I have followed the same steps by purging the cache each time but it really seems random.